# Custom Liquid Swipe Animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-listview, flutter-pageview

I came across a flutter package named [liquid_swipe](https://pub.dev/packages/liquid_swipe) and I want to customize it. Let me explain what I want to acheive.

So liquid_swipes works like a pageview where on right swipe the current page index changes to (index+1) and on left swipe the current page index changes to (index-1) something like this [example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iamSahdeep/liquid_swipe_flutter/master/assets/example.gif).

[image]

So let say there is a list [a, b, c, d, e] and let say we are currently on 'b', so on left swipe I would be on 'a' and on the right swipe I would be on 'c'.

Now I want to customize it, let me explain what I want to achieve. Let takes the list [a, b, c, d, e] and let say we are again on 'b'. I want that on right swipe it goes to 'c' as well as on left swipe too it goes to 'c'. I don't want to go back to 'a' again.

So, what I basically I want is to move forward irrespective on left or right swipe, losing the value which was previously present on left side.

Hope I am able to convey what I want. If more information needed please ask. How can I customize it ?